# Installing Maven, I get this error: fs.js:156 throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, terminal

I install maven by using: `brew install maven`

Then I try to verify by using: `mvn --version`

But I continue to get this error:

```
fs.js:156
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
    at makeCallback (fs.js:156:11)
    at Object.mkdir (fs.js:858:14)
    at Object.target.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mvn/target.js:25:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mvn/target.js:39:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this message?

Comment: Interesting. Does it work from the command line? I've never used homebrew maven, and visual-studio-code might not recognize it. Your problem statement is incomplete; **where** are you getting that message?

Comment: Hi Elliot, I'm using it in the terminal and that's where I'm getting the message as well.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_maven) to install Maven Extenstion?